# Can I add voting to an Issues list on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I've created a SharePoint list on my site from the Issues template. I want to add a column for people to vote on issues they want to see fixed.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible out of the box, but [KWiz](http://kwizcom.com/) has a product that might interest you:

[SharePoint Rating Solution](http://kwizcom.com/ProductPage.asp?ProductId=682)

[image]